# Is there any drawback to using "grep -E" instead of plain "grep"?

Tags: bash, grep

I understand that **GNU** `grep` without `-E` uses basic regex and that `grep -E` uses extended regex. Is there any harm in using `grep -E` even for situations that would work with plain `grep`?

Answer (score 4):

Not much. Back referencing is not possible in grep -E, so you cannot match the same text as previously matched by a `(..)` capturing group (though some `grep` implementations like GNU and BSD `grep` allow it as a non-standard extension).

And if you want to match literal braces or parentheses,`?`,`+`, you now will need to escape them...